# Как добавить комиссию за перевод токена? BEP20 Solidity

Tags: solidity

Суть. Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при переводе токенов кому-либо, списывалась комиссия с отправителя и переводилась на отдельный адрес, созданный специально для комиссий. Я пытался что-то сделать, да по итогу не работает (код в самом низу).

Как сделать комиссию при переводе токена? Использую BEP20

Я так понимаю, нужно изменить что-то в `transfer` или `transferFrom`?

Вот сам transfer (по дефолту)

```
  function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
    _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
    return true;
  }
```

И transferFrom (дефолтный)

```
  function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
    _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
    return true;
  }
```

вот мои попытки:

```
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
    uint256 percent = amount / 10; // считаем процент (10% от суммы)
    _transfer(_msgSender(), own, percent); 
    _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
    _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount));
    _approve(own, _msgSender(), _allowances[own][_msgSender()].add(percent));
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Что-то не совсем понятно суть вопроса. Исходя из предоставленных пары методов, Вы взяли некий контракт и пытаетесь его изменить? Что именно не выходит? Может стоит привести весь код контракта

Comment: @SanyaH это шаблон контракта BEP20 оригинал. Мне нужно чтобы при переводе токенов с одного адреса на другой (или просто на другой адрес) снималась комиссия и отправлялась на адрес, который я укажу. Попытался сделать как было выше, дебаг без ошибок, но на pancakeswap я не могу сделать пул.